# Using a for loop to modify string name when reading data

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

The idea of this part of my code is relatively simple; I am doing a for loop that iterates over some range of integers, and the value of the iteration is placed within a number to string conversion and then called within the for loop to read a data file.

The code snippet:

```
for (int z = 11; z < 33; z++) {
        const std::string filename_1 = "detection";

        int value = z;
        std::string filename_2;
        std::ostringstream convert;
        convert << value;
        filename_2 = convert.str();

        const std::string filename_3 = ".rat";

        const std::string my_file = filename_1 + filename_2 + filename_3;

        // Reading data from the .rat files of the detected signal.
        Reading(my_file, times_det, signal_det);

// Further calculations go here.
```

The code compiles and executes, but after reading out two results of the calculations I am returned with the error:

```
./test
0.527679
0.639159
*** Error in `./test': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000f52a30 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Am I not clearing memory where is necessary? Using .clear() did not remove this issue.

Thank you for the advice!

EDIT: The function 'Reading' for clarity:

```
void Reading(const std::string &filename, rarray<double,1> &times, rarray<std::complex<double>,1> &signal) {
    std::ifstream f(filename.c_str());
    // Read in the signal.
    f >> times;
    f >> signal;
}
```

Comment: At a glance, I don't see how this error would occur. Are you sure it doesn't happen within the `Reading` function? Best practice for asking question involves removing any unknowns from the equation. This helps you and us, since we don't have to assume/guess what's happening elsewhere in your code.

Comment: check your Reading function where you are opening/closing the same file twice in a row. There's nothing wrong with the snippet you provided

Comment: Thank you for the input. I've modified my original post to include the definition of the function, hopefully that will help clarify things.

Comment: @Kam Now there's more I don't know! What's this `rarray`? Do you know this isn't do to `rarray`, or your handling of `times_det` or `signal_det`? You should really reduce the code to the minimal example which reproduces your problem. That alone might get you to the answer, and will allow us to try out the code for ourselves.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde rarray is just a library that I use to generate arrays; times_det and signal_det are rarrays that I had created to pass through the function. The code works beautifully without a for loop; alas, I will try to simplify the problem to see if this can be mitigated. Thanks for your input again!

Comment: Have you tried running your program in `valgrind`?

Comment: Your error is usually caused by writing past the end of an allocation, or trying to free already-freed memory. In what you've given us, rarray, which internally is going to be some kind of dynamically allocated array, is the problem. I feel like you're trying to populate the array with input from the text file, and I don't think that's the way to do it. Imagine like std::vector, you'd have to loop through the file and push back new entries. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

@kam, I tried to reproduce the issue by using the following code and I am suspecting that it may have to do with the rarrays that you are using, but commented out as I don't have the details of the library you are using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void Reading(const std::string &filename, /*rarray< */double /*,1> */ &times, /* rarray<std::complex< */ double /*>,1> */ &signal) {
    std::ifstream f(filename.c_str());
    // std::ifstream f;
    std::string ofile = "o_" + filename;
    std::ofstream o;

    //f.open(filename.c_str());
    o.open(ofile.c_str());

    // Read in the signal.
    f >> times;
    f >> signal;

    cout << "file open :" << f.is_open() << " ";
    cout << times << " " << signal << endl << flush;

    //o << "file open :" << f.is_open() << " ";
    o << times << " " << signal << endl << flush;

    //f.close();
    o.close();
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const std::string filename_1 = "detection";
    const std::string filename_3 = ".rat";
    double times_det = 0.0, signal_det = 0.0;

    for (int z = 11; z < 33; z++) {
        int value = z;
        std::string filename_2;
        std::ostringstream convert;

        convert << value;
        filename_2 = convert.str();

        const std::string my_file = filename_1 + filename_2 + filename_3;

        // Reading data from the .rat files of the detected signal.
        Reading(my_file, times_det, signal_det);

        // Further calculations go here.
    }

    return 0;
}
```